# What happened to Bain and Chiad?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

I just finished *The Shadow Rising* and am wondering what happened to Bain and Chiad, the two Aiel accompanying Perrin and Faile. I'm not sure if I missed something in the end of *The Shadow Rising* that concluded their character arc.

Please do not spoil anything from later books.

Comment: pretty sure there fine, do you have a specific instance your confused about

Comment: @Himarm - It seemed that there was a relationship between them and the male Aiel in the group that Jordan was going to expound on.

Comment: they continue their relationship dance through the end of the series, but anything other then that is spoilers

Comment: @Himarm - ok thank you. I just wasn't sure if I missed something big.

Comment: I've mentioned a few things from later books in my answer, but hidden them behind spoilertags - don't click if you don't want to see them. Let me know if you'd like me to remove anything from my answer altogether.

Answer (score 3):

### No, their character arc isn't concluded.

The end of *The Shadow Rising* doesn't really do anything conclusive with the characters of Bain and Chiad; they're still with Perrin and Faile in the Two Rivers, and we just need to wait for that plotline to start moving again.

As it happens, you'll have quite a long wait, because this is one of those times in the series when one of the most major characters completely disappears for the length of a book and their plotline is only picked up again in the next book. So you won't be seeing Perrin, Faile, Bain, or Chiad throughout *The Fires of Heaven*, and we only return to the Two Rivers at the start of *Lord of Chaos*, when

> Perrin decides that he needs to go to Rand. Later on in the book, Bain and Chiad are with Perrin and Faile when they arrive in Caemlyn to see Rand.

In *A Crown of Swords* and *The Path of Daggers*, they

> also accompany Perrin and Faile to Ghealdan, and they're with Faile when she's kidnapped by the Shaido and taken as *gai'shain*.

So as you can see, they're still going to be cropping up in the story for quite a while yet. However, they're never again quite such *major* characters as they were in certain parts of *The Shadow Rising*.